# Convert string in array regex

Tags: ruby, regex

I have string `"1 potato chips at 3.99"`

I want to convert this in to array using regex `["1", "potato chips", 3.99]`

Currenty i am doing this

```
/^([\d\s\.\/]+)\s+(.*)\s+([\d\s\.\/]+)$/.match(input).to_a
```

But it gives me output as

```
[" 1 book at 12.99", " 1", "book at", "12.99"]
```

Comment: `["1", "potato chips", 3.99]` is not a regex.--Ok, I see you are Indian. I will edit it.

Comment: this is output i get

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What is `input`? Is it the string that you showed at the beginning? If so, this situation cannot be reproduced.

Comment: What is the idea here? How do you define the entities that interest you as atomic?

Comment: I have this string "1 potato chips at 3.99" and i want to convert it like this ["1", "potato chips", 3.99]

Comment: Try to define your question that contains: code, input, expected output, actual output or errors.

Comment: @Mukesh, a person could easily just return `["1", "potato chips", 3.99]`. But I'm guessing there are other strings that you want this to work for. So how do you differentiate between what should be included and what should be omitted, what should be split and what should be left together?

Comment: Ok I need a regex that will match "1 potato chips at 3.99" except 'at'

Comment: `"1 potato chips at 3.99".split(' at').join`

Comment: @ndn To get what OP stated in question: `"1 potato chips at 3.99".split(/(?<=\d)\s+| at |\s+(?=\d)/)`.

Comment: @mudasobwa, not what he stated at the comments *Ok I need a regex that will match "1 potato chips at 3.99" except 'at'*. For me it's unclear what he wants to achieve in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With conversion to an array:

```
/^\s*(\d+)\s+(.*?)\s+\w+\s+([0-9.]+)$/
       .match("1 potato chips at 3.99")
       .to_a.tap { |a| a.shift }
#⇒ [
#  [0] "1",
#  [1] "potato chips",
#  [2] "3.99"
#]
```

or, better:

```
/^\s*(\d+)\s+(.*?)\s+\w+\s+([0-9.]+)$/
       .match("1 potato chips at 3.99").captures
```

using split (inspired by @ndn):

```
"1 potato chips at 3.99".split(/(?<=\d)\s+| at |\s+(?=\d)/)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
(?:\d+\.?)+|[^\d]+
```

[Regex live here.](https://regex101.com/r/dI3cC0/2)

Explaining:

```
(?:\d+\.?)+      # as many numbers and/or dots as possible
|[^\d]+          # OR not numbers
```

Hope it helps.